# How to check the results of graph_db.get_indexed_node for empty?

Tags: neo4j, nonetype, py2neo

How can I test if a / no NODE has been found?

```
NODE = graph_db.get_indexed_node("index", "ID", "myID")
if (NODE == None):
    print "None found"
    exit()
```

unfortunately results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 275, in foobar
    if (NODE == None):
  File "...\py2neo\neo4j.py", line 1499, in __eq__
    return _Entity.__eq__(self, other)
  File "...\py2neo\neo4j.py", line 324, in __eq__
    return self._resource == other._resource
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_resource'
```

because class 'py2neo.neo4j.Node' cannot be compared with "None".

How to check the results of graph_db.get_indexed_node for empty?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround:

```
assert ( type(NODE) != type(None) )
```

yiehah! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is to use:

```
if node is None:
    ...
```

or

```
assert Node is not None
```

When comparing with constants, always use `is` rather than `==`.